# Chrome flag for testing getDisplayMedia() without having to grant permission every time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, permissions

I'm programmatically capturing my screen in JS using `getDisplayMedia()` and Chrome has a safety feature that requires the user to grant permission for the capture of a specific Display **every single time the function is invoked**.

Is there any way to persist permissions? I assume a debug flag for something like this exists somewhere, or do I have to go through the effort of packaging this into an extension (would that even work)? Is there any simple-enough way to capture the screen besides `getDisplayMedia()` that I might be able to use as an alternative if there are no other options?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it feels like it would be a security issue if websites would persist this permission....

Comment: @vanowm It is, but having it available as a flag for development would be nice. Maybe firefox has it hmmm

Comment: Please use [chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabCapture/#method-getMediaStreamId).

Answer (score 1):

For development purposes, you can run Chrome with the `"--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream"` [command-line switch](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags/) to bypass the browser prompt, the screen would be selected by default if no options are passed for instance.

Note that you will still need a user gesture for `getDisplayMedia()` though.